# Having trouble converting Pig Latin JavaScript function to a GUI

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

I'm stuck on this project of mine. I have a Pig Latin project that works in a console. But I'm trying to convert it to a GUI. I thought I could just use the function I already built and add an input field. But it's not working.

Here's my JS.

```
const pigLatin = (word) => {

document.getElementById("translate").value;


// Your code here
word = word.trim().toLowerCase();
const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
const myWord = word.split("");
let newWord = "";


if (vowels.includes(myWord[0])) {
myWord.push('yay');
for (let i = 0; i < myWord.length; i++) {
  newWord = newWord + myWord[i];
}
return newWord;
} else {
for (let i = 0; i < myWord.length; i++) {
  if ( (vowels.includes(myWord[i]))) {
    newWord = myWord.slice(i, myWord.length).concat(newWord).join('') + 'ay';
    return newWord;
   } else {
     newWord = newWord.concat(myWord[i])

   }

      }}}
```

My HTML

```
 <body>
<h1>Pig Latin Translator!</h1>
<hr/>
<div id="display-element">

  <input id="translate" type="text" placeholder="Enter word here">
  <button onclick="pigLatin()">Submit</button>
</div>
<hr/>

<div id="output">
</div>


<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Right now I'm getting an error of :

```
   Uncaught TypeError:

   Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
    at pigLatin (main.js:24)
   at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:13)
       pigLatin @ main.js:24
        onclick @ index.html:13
```

Am I close or do I need to start over?

Comment: So you mean you obtained this code somewhere else *and* want to put a GUI on it?

Comment: Hello! I wrote the JS code but I'm having trouble putting a GUI on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest possible patch:

```
-  <button onclick="pigLatin()">Submit</button> 
+  <button onclick="document.getElementById('output').textContent=pigLatin(document.getElementById('translate').value)">Submit</button>
```

This is of course nowhere near "best practice," but I suppose this is what you need since this is a toy project and you just need it working with your HTML interface.

Normally you would put the two controls in a form and attach the `submit` event handler with either `addEventHandler` or `onsubmit` and get the control values in the handler function.

Comment: Thank you! That did work, but you're right, I should learn the most recommended method.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. Only minor errors in your code.

You are not passing any parameter into your `pigLatin` function from your markup (HTML). In your markup, you have the function `pigLatin()`, without a (`word`) parameter, but you are requiring a parameter in your JavaScript `pigLatin(word)`. That is why when JavaScript tries to perform `word.trim()`, `word` is undefined ans so it says *I cannot perform the `trim` method on an `undefined` value`*.

So, this is what you should do.

1. In your JavaScript, remove the `word` parameter to the `pigLatin` function (because you are not passing anything to it actually from your markup).
2. Set `word` to `document.getElementById("translate").value;` by doing this

`let word = document.getElementById("translate").value;`

This will retrieve the value of whatever you typed in the input box and pass it to `word`

You are okay from there.

Comment: Thank you for your time! Ok so I did that. And now in my GUI. Nothing happens after I hit submit. Do I need an output?